# Problem with populating lists from asynchronous Retrofit call response

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, retrofit

I am trying to populate lists with data from my database by making a call with retrofit. The call is inside a method, which maps the response to a local list and returns it. The problem is, the local list gets returned before it is populated because the call is asynchronous and an empty list is returned. The response itself has all the data needed. How could this be solved?

**Piece of code where the method is called**

```
fragments = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, RowFragment>();
int subjectCount = this.getTeachers(jwt).size();

for(int i = 0; i < subjectCount; i++){
      RowFragment fragment = new RowFragment();
      fragments.put(i, fragment);
}
```

**The method**

```
public List<Teacher> getTeachers(String jwt){

        APIService apiService = ApiServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, jwt);
        Call<List<Teacher>> call = apiService.getTeachers();
        List<Teacher> tempTeachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Teacher>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Teacher>> call, Response<List<Teacher>> response){
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    if(response.body().isEmpty() != true){
                        tempTeachers.addAll(response.body());
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(BrowseActivity.this, "You have no teachers assigned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(BrowseActivity.this, "You are not authorized, please log in again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Teacher>> call, Throwable err) {
                Log.i("err", err.getMessage());
            }
        });
        return tempTeachers;
    }
```

**The response**

```
200 GET https://bakalaurinis.azurewebsites.net/studentmaterial

Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 19 Apr 2021 19:50:06 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Set-Cookie:ARRAffinitySameSite=22a7daa836b64a8ce56c907737553d08297ff2e76cd06a1f52c29956b9a85c17;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=bakalaurinis.azurewebsites.net
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

[{"name":"teacher","surname":"teacher","subject":"teacher","userId":25,"schoolId":5},{"name":"teacher2","surname":"teacher2","subject":"Chemistry","userId":28,"schoolId":5},{"name":"teacher3","surname":"teacher3","subject":"Physics","userId":29,"schoolId":5},{"name":"teacher4","surname":"teacher4","subject":"Math","userId":30,"schoolId":5}]
```

**Teacher class**

```
public class Teacher {
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String subject;
    public int userId;
    public int schoolId;

    public Teacher(String name, String surname, String subject, int userId, int schoolId){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
    }
}
```

The call could be made synchronous, but if I understand correctly android would then throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you doing like that, what happen if the connection is weak? The value will be null/empty. If you want to achieve like this, maybe you need to use Coroutine and etc. So this case, you will have to list them/get all these value inside the method `onResponse`. The value will not be null. Change the type method `getTeachers` to `void`

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(Call<List<Teacher>> call, Response<List<Teacher>> response){
     if(response.isSuccessful()){
         if(response.body().isEmpty() != true){
            tempTeachers.addAll(response.body());
            //Do it here
            fragments = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, RowFragment>();
            final int subjectCount = tempTeachers.size();

            for(int i = 0; i < subjectCount; i++){
                RowFragment fragment = new RowFragment();
                fragments.put(i, fragment);
            }
         }
         else{
            Toast.makeText(BrowseActivity.this, "You have no teachers assigned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
     else{
        Toast.makeText(BrowseActivity.this, "You are not authorized, please log in again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }
```